# In Mongoose, add or update a object to an array by field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

My model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TelemetrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  MQTT: {
    Id: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  },
  Presets: [{
    Id: Number,
    Message: String,
  }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Telemetry', TelemetrySchema);
```

What I would like to do:

If the object with the specified Id already exists, overwrite it. If the object does not yet exist, create a new one with the specified Id.

I am receiving a single `Preset` object, and how Presets in model should look like:

t=0: `{Id: 1, Message: 'A'}` -> `[{Id: 1, Message: 'A'}]`

t=1: `{Id: 2, Message: 'B'}` -> `[{Id: 1, Message: 'A'}, {Id: 2, Message: 'B'}]`

t=3: `{Id: 1, Message: 'Z'}` -> `[{Id: 1, Message: 'Z'}, {Id: 2, Message: 'B'}]`

Is it possible to do this with just one `findOneAndUpdate`? I have a working solution, but I don't really like it...

```js
client.on('message', async (topic, payload) => {
  const s = payload.toString();
  const p = JSON.parse(s);
  const id = topic.split('/');

  const existingTelemetry = await Telemetry.findOne({
    'MQTT.Id': id[1],
    'Presets.Id': p.Id,
  });

  if (existingTelemetry) {
    // If an object with the same id exists, update the existing object
    await Telemetry.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        'MQTT.Id': id[1],
        'Presets.Id': p.Id,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          'Presets.$': p,
        },
      },
      {
        new: true,
        omitUndefined: true,
      },
    );
  } else {
    // If no object with the same id exists, add the new object
    await Telemetry.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        'MQTT.Id': id[1],
      },
      {
        $addToSet: {
          Presets: p,
        },
      },
      {
        upsert: true,
        new: true,
        omitUndefined: true,
      },
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: idk maybe something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/pvCmBG0IliC

Comment: same thign https://mongoplayground.net/p/1bhwg9H3fHH

Comment: here to upsert if mqtt also not exists  https://mongoplayground.net/p/KfhO91SdMBM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I perform updates in similar scenarios and I will explain why I do it this way instead of an aggregation pipeline.

Firstly, an aggregation pipeline to do this will of course work. However, when you come to update the code in 3/6/12/x months time you will need to spend some brain power reading the pipeline and figure out what the hell you wrote. With aggregation pipelines they can be hard to read after considerable time away and can be difficult to tweak if your schema changes, at least that's how I feel.

Secondly, when you look at the code below it's clear and easy for you and your team to see what's going on.

Lastly, and this is the only difference from your code, is that **some** of the time in the code below you only need to hit the database **once** becuase the `if(!doc)` might only be `true` infrequently. Whereas in your code above you will **always** hit the database **twice** (1x `findOne` + 1x `findOneAndUpdate`).

Now depending on how frequently those updates get a match first time it could be 60/70/80% of the time so the second `findOneAndUpdate` in the `if(!doc)` never gets fired or only fires 10/20/30% of the time. That could be an acceptable tolerance.

```
// Assign the return value to 'doc'
const doc = await Telemetry.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
       'MQTT.Id': id[1],
       'Presets.Id': p.Id,
    },
    {
       $set: {
          'Presets.$': p,
       },
    },
    {
       new: true,
       omitUndefined: true,
    },
);
if(!doc){ //< There was no match and no update so $addToSet
   await Telemetry.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
         'MQTT.Id': id[1],
      },
      {
         $addToSet: {
            Presets: p,
         },
      },
      {
         upsert: true,
         new: true,
         omitUndefined: true,
      },
   );
}
```